# Confluent Hypergeometric Differential Equation

Tags: integration

Is it possible to convert a Differential equation of the form
$\left( {1 - z} \right)G''\left( z \right) - \frac{1}{{{c_1}}}\left\{ {{c_1} + {c_2}\left( {1 - z} \right) + {c_3}} \right\}G'\left( z \right) + \frac{{{c_2}}}{{{c_1}}}G\left( z \right) = 0 $ 
into Confluent Hypergeometric Differential Equation which is of the form $zG''\left( z \right) + (b - z)G'\left( z \right) - aG\left( z \right) = 0$.

Comment: I tried, but I couldn't convert the given Differential equation into Confluent Hypergeometric

Comment: Take $G(z) = (z - 1)^{-c_3/c_1} g(Z)$, $Z = c_2 (z - 1)/c_1$. You'll get Kummer's equation on $g(Z)$ (with $a = b$).

Comment: Thank you so much.